# LUIS intent dialog just triggered in the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

It’s my first time with chatbots and there are some quite new concepts going on for me. This dialog idea still makes me a bit confused.

I’m integrating LUIS with my bot to enable the user to search for products in my database. My integration starts with something like this:

```
const intents = new builder.IntentDialog({
  recognizers: [greeting, new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl)],
  intentThreshold: 0.2,
  recognizeOrder: builder.RecognizeOrder.series,
});
```

and then

```
intents.matches('LS_SearchProducts', '/lsSearchProducts');
```

where “**LS_SearchProducts**” is my LUIS intent.

In my dialog

```
bot.dialog('/lsSearchProducts', [ 5 functions flow ]);
```

I have 5 functions to handle my flow. In the last one I do:

```
session.endDialog();
```

And everything is working nicely in the first time and that’s my problem. Everything is working fine **JUST** in the **FIRST** time. The dialog is not triggered again unless I start the server again or deploy again.

ex:

User types: “ketchup heinz”

The bot works as expected.

Then

User types again: “ketchup heinz” and nothing happens. I’m expecting to go through the same process again, even because it could be another product. Btw when I do with another product “mustard heinz” it’s not triggered either.

What I’m getting wrong here? My other custom recognizer “greeting” is just working fine. I can always type “hello” and it’s gonna always be triggered.

I've checked the others similar questions and it seems to be something else.

Comment: Is there a particular tutorial you are following? Also, it looks like you are using the V3 Node SDK - is that correct?

Comment: I didn't think about the version. That's what I have at the moment.     "botbuilder": "^3.15.*", "botbuilder-azure": "^3.1.*"

Comment: I'm not following any tutorial. Just went throughout a lot of different examples to understand the concepts and ended up building my one using differente examples as the base.

Comment: `IntentDialog` is an older approach to setting up a LUIS Bot and is not the preferred method. Instead, you should add the recognizers to the bot and use a `triggerAction` on each dialog. Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/intelligence-LUIS) on Microsoft's GitHub Repository for an example.

Comment: Did changing the structure resolve the issue or are you still seeing the same issue?

Comment: I'm following your suggestion to try v4. It seems to make sense the samples doesn't work straightway, I'm having to fix and research a bit. Almost there. When I'm done will return with the result.

Comment: The structure I mentioned in my previous comment is the recommended way to set up LUIS in V3 of the Botframework. If you are still working in V3, I would recommend looking at the [V3 LUIS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for more clarification on how to set it up. Otherwise, if you upgraded your project to V4 of the Botframework, take a look at the [V4 LUIS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs).

Comment: You are right. You were talking about V3. You made me think about the version and when I checked for it I realised that V4 was just released. Playing around with it right now. I'm wondering what would be the right answer to this question now.

Comment: Correct, Microsoft release v4 of the BotBuilder Framework in early September. Again, to start working on a v4 LUIS bot, I would look at the [v4 LUIS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs), and I would also encourage you to look at the [nlp-with-luis](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/12.nlp-with-luis) in Microsoft's BotBuilder Samples repository. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't encounter an issue with the LUIS only being triggered once in the new framework, but if you do, please let me know, and I can help you diagnosis the issue further.